# Data not being added to Redis during integration test

Tags: node.js, express, redis, jestjs, supertest

I am attempting to write a integration test for my expressjs router with a Redis store.

```
const request = require('supertest'); 
const redisClient = require('../../startup/redis-client');

describe('/api/', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        server = require('../../index');
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        await redisClient.flushAll();
        await redisClient.disconnect();
        server.close();
    });

    describe('GET /:key',  () => {
        it('should return the key', async () => {
            console.log(redisClient);

            await redisClient.set('key1', 'value1');

            
            await redisClient.set('key2', 'value2');

            const res = await request(server).get('/api/key1');

            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            expect(res.body).toBe('value1');
        });
    });
});
```

The resulting data looks like this:

```
[

  {

    id: '1647263665426-0',

    message: [Object: null prototype] { key1: 'value1' }

  }

]
```

My route handler code:

```
        const result = await redisClient.get(key);
        
        console.log(result);

        if(result && result[0] && result[0].message)
        {
            res.send(result[0].message[`${key}`]);
        } else {
            res.status(404).send("Key not found.");
        }
```

Is there a reason `result[0].message['${key}'])` or `result[0].message.key` does not work? What is the correct way to get the 'value1' from this returned object from Redis?

Comment: Well, uhm, do you get any results from those console logs? And if so - what do they say? :)
I am unaware of the Redis client you're using, but typically they allow **either** await/async, **or** a callback. You're using both, and I'm a bit concerned that might cause an issue.

Comment: @AndreyPopov yeah you may be right, I only added that stuff when trying to debug what was going on more, will remove. The client log looks like it client is fine and being created. The other logs weren't printing anything (so may just be being ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the response for node-redis to a valid object allowed me to return the value I expected to.

```
const resultObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0].message));
res.send(resultObject[key]);
```